# How to set ext_editor to True for all new users?

Tags: plone

I'm using Plone 4.1 and collective.externaleditor. I would like that whenever a new user is created, his personal preference ext_editor be set to True.

I made a subscriber to the user creation event, but I can't change that property:

**configure.zcml:**

```
 ...
 <subscriber
      for="Products.PluggableAuthService.interfaces.events.IPrincipalCreatedEvent"
      handler=".events.newUser"
      />
```

**events.py:**

```
from zope.app.component.hooks import getSite
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

def newUser(user):
    '''Sets external editor property to True for new users.'''
    mtool = getToolByName(getSite(), 'portal_membership')
    # what should i put here?
    user.principal.setProperties({'ext_editor': True})
```

newUser isn't doing its work. user.principal's type is Ploneuser. It doesn't have a setMemberProperties method, so I don't know what to do.

collective.externaleditor add a property 'ext_editor' to control panel too, so I could change it programmatically.

How can I set ext_editor to True for new created users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer I found.

**profiles/default/memberdata_properties.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_memberdata" meta_type="Plone Memberdata Tool">
 <property name="ext_editor" type="boolean">True</property>
</object>
```

Comment: So much easier when people find the answer before I get to a question. :-P